# How to get absolute path to Grails application

Tags: grails

In my application, a login controller should return redirect URL if client is authorized:

```
<path to grails app> + <another controller, method, params>
```

How can I get application URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to build a URL using the grails tags [as method calls](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#tagsAsMethodCalls).  [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) is likely what you want.  This has `action`, `controller`, `params` and `absolute` as options to get a full URL to a controller action (you may need to configure the base url as noted in the docs).  In an example in the first link, something like this would get the absolute URL to that resource:

```
g.createLink(action:"myact", controller:"somecontroller", params:[foo:'bar', boo:'far'], absolute:true)
```

Answer (score 0):

For generic approach you can inject [LinkGenerator](http://docs.grails.org/5.1.2/api/grails/web/mapping/LinkGenerator.html) and then call

```
linkGenerator.link(controller: "foo", action: "bar", absolute: true)
```

For some reason, tag use completely different logic.